# using the `find` command with -exec for a lot of files, how can I compare the output against a value?

Tags: bash, command-line, find, imagemagick

I am trying to iterate over a large number of images and check their 'mean' value using ImageMagick.

The following command finds the images I want to check, and executes the correct command on them.

```
find `pwd` -type f -name "*.png" -exec /usr/bin/identify -ping -format "%[mean]" info: {} \;
```

Now I want to compare the output to see if it comes up with a certain value, 942.333

How can I get the output of each value that find returns to check and spit out the filename of any matched image who has the ouput of 942.333 from my command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `identify` command so it outputs the filename and the mean, then use `grep`:

```
find `pwd` -type f -name "*.png" -exec identify -ping -format "%[mean] %f\n" {} \; | grep "942.333"
```

Or, if you really have lots of images, you could put all your lovely CPU cores to work and do them in parallel, using GNU Parallel:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | parallel -m -0 'identify -ping -format "%[mean] %f\n" {1}' | grep ...
```